# Do you know some good python script for getting bilingual dictionaries or translating multiple words from Glosbe?

Tags: python, api, translation, dictionary, web-apis

I am looking for a python script or API with I can translate multiple words from Glosbe and some detail about the usage.

Comment: It sounds like it would be easy to write yourself with Requests.

Comment: Have you tried Googling it? I searched “glosbe python” and found several projects.